# How can I run individual c# files without having to make a project?

Tags: c#, .net

sorry if this is a newbie question but I'm starting with c# in visual studio code and am currently using the `dotnet new console` command to make a new project, then rename it and use the `dotnet run` command to run it. is there a way to run a file without having to make a project for it? or is that not how it works in c#?
 - for example I want a file that just contains a namespace that contains a class that I want to use in a project.

Comment: Do you need to actually have an .exe file to run?  If not, you could use something like LinqPad which supports c# 7 syntax and just save and run your code.  No project needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly run the c# compiler, found at c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\\csc.exe or c:\windows\microsoft.net\Framework64\\csc.exe, but it will likely be far easier to use a project file. If you have msbuild installed (I don't know whether VS.Code uses it or not) you could also use that as a build manager.

Comment: I do have msbuild but when I do msbuild {filename} it returns an error saying "data at root level is invalid". Do you know what that means?